# How to return 'Todays Orders' using a predicate builder

Tags: java, spring, jpa, predicate, specifications

I am trying to build a predicate where I return a list of orders based on a orderType - eg TodaysOrders, AllOrders, PendingOrders, FailedOrders etc.

For TodaysOrders, I want to return just the orders with todays date rather than bookings in the past 24 hours.

I tried the below snippet and this returns the past 24 hours.

> if (orderType == todaysOrders) {
> predicate = builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(RECEIVED_DATE),
> LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1));

I tried the below snippet and this returns 0 results as there is no others with the exact time stamp as LocalDateTime.now()

> if (orderType == todaysOrders) {
> predicate = builder.equal(root.get(RECEIVED_DATE),
> LocalDateTime.now();

Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

RECEIEVED_DATE is a column in an ordersRepository and is type LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime, and call

```
if (orderType == todaysOrders) {
    predicate = builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(RECEIVED_DATE), 
                LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay());
}
```

Comment: I need to use LocalDateTime to ensure data is in the correct format when I return it. I did find a solution though.        
I declared a new variable called todayWithoutTime.
  LocalDateTime todayWithoutTime = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
And then did a greaterThanOrEqual to predicate.
predicate = builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(RECEIVED_DATE), todayWithoutTime);
Thanks for the help though 